# In need of a virtual display or similar solution

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors connected to the computer (running Windows 7). They are in extended mode. The secondary one is out of sight (behind a wall) and I would like to see what's actually being displayed on it. Mirroring the monitors is not an option, because I need the other one for a different task.

I thought about finding a software which enables virtual displays and have a virtual display - mirroring the secondary one - being shown on the primary monitor. I searched for such a software, but couldn't find one. The answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor/62514#62514) suggests two programs, but none of them work. The Matrox one appears to be working only with Matrox hardware (I have an nVidia card) and the other link is broken.

Now, my question is: is there any other software/way which can be used to create a virtual monitor? Or: Does anyone have another solution to the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: Do you need this to show something specific, e.g. a slideshow or web page or something like that? Just asking because some programs might already include such functionality as some kind of presentation mode.

Comment: The secondary monitor is being used for displaying a custom software, which starts in full screen. The software is started from another program and moved to the secondary screen, but moving it there doesn't always work. That's why I would like to see in real-time what's happening on the secondary monitor, to make sure everything works.

Comment: Well, you could set up a web cam with Wi-Fi and get the image back that way :)