# Use TeamViewer for another PC to act as a 2nd Monitor?

Tags: display, teamviewer

I have a second standalone PC with TeamViewer installed.  Is there any way I can use TeamViewer to set it up to serve as a second screen - (extend, not duplicate)?  i.e., the other PC should basically be showing a different screen to my PC, via TeamViewer.

Comment: Where was similar question answered here http://superuser.com/a/796884/182092

Comment: The question is now clear, but it's a duplicate.  The duplicate is referenced in the comment, above and in Mike Chase's answer.  So there would be limited benefit to reopen and then close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this method. Fake that you have a second desktop, and then use team viewer to view the second desktop. Here's the link: [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

You could only do this if you wanted a monitor clone - it would not work if you wanted a typical "extended desktop" dual monitor setup.

By Teamviewing one PC from another, you could see teh contents of the target machine on both monitors, but you cannot use it to extend one PC monitor to another.

What you want could be accomplished wiht a couple of long(ish) cables and either a dual-port graphics card or possibly a splitter (assuming your GPU supports it)