# Fake Montitor for TeamViewer on Laptop with closed lid

Tags: display, emulator

I want to use my old laptop remotely (teamviewer) with closed lid. The problem is that the laptop will stop rendering windowcontent when the lid is closed. I found this answer: https://superuser.com/a/988097/825553 where it was suggested to conntect a 102 ohm resitor on the vga-pin 2 & 6.

My question: can I use a 100 ohm instead of a 102 ohm to fake a connected monitor?

Comment: What version of windows are you using? Modern windows has a setting in the PowerManagement that says: What to do when the lid is closed: nothing

Comment: I'm useing Windows 10 and the setting is already set to "do nothing" - but when the lid is closed, the laptop stops useing the grafikcard (or updateing the GPU-Memory, im not shure) and when i connect with that laptop via teamviewer some windows are not updating their content (content is frozen or just black). So it looks like i have to let win10 think that there is another monitor attached and active...

Comment: Given that you use TeamViewer, try to enable the TeamViewer monitor driver and see if that helps. You can do so from the advanced options.

Comment: I installed the TeamViewer monitor driver but still have "frozen" windowcontent.

Comment: ok, restarting the laptop after installing the driver solved it. thx bro :)

Comment: I've posted an answer. Feel free to mark it solved so others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you use TeamViewer, you may want to try installing teamviewer's monitor driver. This should mean that teamviewer will use a virtual driver that works in any circumstances where a monitor is required. This should also allow you to use any resolution you need that is normally not supported by your monitor.

A restart may be required after you enable the monitor driver.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me. I am running Windows 10 v1909....

With the lid closed, do the following (even though you don't see anything - Windows is still running, but it is not sending anything to a closed display):

1. **Windows Key** + letter '**P**' (will open the setting for multiple displays *)
2. Press Enter

If the above doesn't work, press **Windows key** + '**P**' more than once to toggle between different options:

**PC screen only /  Duplicate / Extend / Second screen only**

***IMPORTANT** Make sure you have enabled the TeamViewer option **Send key combinations** for the remote computer

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1141971/babble2fish) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1141972/babble2fish). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: In other words, rather than submit the [same Suggested Edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/954983) yet again, please ask the staff to merge your two accounts.  After that, you can perform *your own* edits unimpeded.