# Is there a way to add a virtual display to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, obs-studio

I'm asking if there is a way to add a virtual display to Windows 10.

(No, I don't mean virtual desktop. Like a virtual hardware device.)

The virtual display should show up in Device Manager, and should be visible.

[image: Image of Windows Device Manager Display adapters]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a fake second display be enabled in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/947291/can-a-fake-second-display-be-enabled-in-windows-10)

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. Why do you want to add a virtual display? You tagged `obs-studio`. In what way is OBS Studio related to your problem?

Answer (score -3):

If you need extra desktops you can add virtual desktops on your keyboard by  pressing `CTRL`+`Win`+`D`.

This duplicates the number of desktops you have so you can open things on more desktops with only 1 screen or more. If you have 2 screens you now have 4 desktops you can switch by using `CTRL`+`Win`+`left/right arrow`. Alternatively you can press `Win`+`TAB` to switch.

You can then right click any open application and send it to another desktop. You can create more desktops as needed. These won't show in device manager though as they are virtual desktops, nota hardware devices.

Comment: Welcome to the community :-) I edited your answer for readability. Unfortunately it's not applicable - you're advising how to create virtual _desktops_, and the OP is talking about virtual HW devices which _do_ show up in the Device Manager. Please note that SE communities are not discussion boards.  I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and reading through the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to lean how these communities work. In general checking the Help is a good idea in every new SE community you join, rules differ.