# Do I need a 4K display to record my screen @ 4K resolution?

Tags: display, gpu, screen-recorder, screenresolution

If I have a 4090 GPU card that is capable of 8K video outputs(I guess), but my display is a Full HD (2K I guess) monitor, Can I record my screen at 4K resolution using OBS? Or I need to buy a 4K monitor?

Comment: You'll have to create a second fake monitor, as described here : https://superuser.com/a/1706401/714576

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this can't be easily done by setting the canvas size, etc. to 4K/8K in OBS, as your graphics card still only outputs 2048*1080 resolution.

You can alternatively use a 4K video capture card, which also has an HDMI input and output.

Windows will then adapt to the 4K capability of the capture card, which you can use as video input in OBS and then pass the HDMI output to your monitor.

This could be cheaper than buying a new monitor. But remember to check what refresh rate the capture card supports. For example, you may have a 120Hz monitor, but the capture card only supports 60Hz. In this case, your monitor would only run at 60Hz.

There is no software option for this in Windows and even if there was such an option, it would (in my experience from other similar projects) be very jerky and would not run smoothly.