# Change screen or window resolution to 4096 x 4096

Tags: windows, resolution

I'm running a program which automatically saves images of the current view.

I need an image from that program saved with 4096 x 4096 resolution but of course my screen can't go to that resolution.

If I state inside the program that I want images with 4096 x 4096 pixels it just print screens with 1256 x 800 which is my current desktop resolution.

Is there any way of "tricking" the program into opening a 4096 x 4096 window (it would then be dragged around in my 1256 x 800 desktop) and saving those images like I want?

I already tried [Infinite Screen](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/infinite_screen.pl) and searched a lot on the internet but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Btw, I'm on Windows 8

Comment: The `xrandr` function on Linux does exactly what you want. If it's a one-off job, maybe you could boot a LiveCD.

Comment: As a last resource I can do that yeah. Do you know of any way of doing the same in Windows?

Comment: I am afraid not: that's why I suggested Linux. I'll be interested if you find a Windows solution. There may be some way to kid the system that it has a second, virtual display of your desired resolution.

Comment: Some of [these answers](http://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor) or [these](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2351516) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a solution.

Using GiMeSpace Desktop Extender solves the problem. Within this application I can set the size (in pixels) of each window.