# How to create a Ghost Monitor in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Ive made some research on the web and didn't found any answers and as its always been welcoming here here's my question.

Question:
Is it possible to make a Ghost Monitor ("Fake Monitor/Secondary Monitor") on windows 10?  I found the following topic: [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor),but apparently its not working in Windows 10. Any other means of doing so without any third party software.

Comment: What's your end goal in mind with doing this?

Comment: I'll be using Team-viewer to extend my Main computer to my Laptop which sits at the side of my desktop PC. And I would like to do this using Team-viewer instead of 3rd Party Software.