# Emulating Computer Monitor and Mouse With out having a screen plugged in

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, mouse

So we have a system that is in an enclosed rack that CANNOT have a monitor attached to it and is contolled using remote desktop. What we have realised is that as soon as we have disconnected from the session the "monitor" view and mouse cease to exist.

This is causing a problem for us as we have a system that has to move the mouse to click objects across multiple windows on the windows desktop (I know this probably doesn't sound like a good idea but it has to be done this way).

So our question is wether there is some sort of emulator that can create a display that is persisant and is addressable in screen pixels for mouse movement.

The system has to be able to take multiple screen shots of the desktop and windows to try and find the items that it is looking for and them move the mouse this position on an identical window using the screen coordinates.

The whole system works perfectly over the remote desktop connection (even if it keeps stealing my host mouse which is why we need it to be independent) and locally on a computer with a screen plugged in.

We considered a Virtual OS host like virtual box but this presents much bigger problems as the system is a high performance system on an isolated protected network that makes it extrememly hard to forward the multiple network cards each connected to different networks. So this would cause a lot more issues wether it lags the system or if it would even work at all. (Also just thinking the licence key probably isn't "forwardable" on from the host system to a virtual OS so this would be another problem).

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. I do not mind having to create a solution that is very low level to attempt to fake the screen but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor).

Comment: @harrymc Neither of these options worked unfortunatley as they were more designed to extend a physical monitor not replace a physical monitor