# How can I offset my monitor from the center?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, display-settings

This question might be a bit odd, but due to a damaged screen, I need to adjust my LG 32 inch 4K monitor to be offset from the center. I've already adjusted the resolution to reduce the width. Now, I want to have the screen right-aligned basically. How can I get this done?

I am using Windows 10 and have an AMD Radeon graphic card (RX 540) on a HP laptop with an Intel chip (Intel UHD Graphics 620). I can give more information if necessary.

Googling only helped with the opposite problem.

Comment: Does your monitor have an on-screen-display, frequently referred to as OSD that enables you to manipulate the image management independently of the computer? In the "old days," one had physical knobs to turn, but today it's push a button, push another button, select menu items, etc. to get the results you require. One of those items would be horizontal placement. If you provide a model number, more information may be forthcoming.

Comment: LG 32UD99-W is the model number. I do have such a knob, but I can't seem to find horizontal placement.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty dated, but I haven't found any great answers out there (I have a damaged screen, too). It seems like the ability to move displays up/down/left/right is legacy technology and doesn't apply to new digital inputs - at least as far as I can tell.

The solution I am using is Fancy Zones which is a tool in Windows PowerToys. I have left the original display resolution, but I have set a zone so that it is easy to drag and drop windows to the broken screen and have them automatically re-size to the non-broken display area. I have two screens, so it is my secondary screen, but the idea might still work for one screen... Anyway, good luck! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones

Answer (score 0):

Look for this icon [image: here] in the windows 10 taskbar.

If you right click it, you have two options: Graphic Properties and Graphic Options.

Clicking on the first, a window it will open, if you then click Display you can change the aspect ratio, scaling, center, etc. (see also Advanced options).

Clicking on the second, a menu will open, you can then try Panel Fit and Custom Resolutions (the first one has 4 options to look at).

With one of this you should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, I only have one option which options the Intel UHD Graphic options (I think, it's called settings). There I can change the resolution, but I can't offset from the center there.

Comment: Oh that's strange, maybe you have to update drivers

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

You could also consider the above solution to make Windows to have two virtual monitor - mapped to a single physical monitor. and use the virtual monitor on the right as your main desktop. Ignore the left.

Comment: Thanks, this might be a clever way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, your monitor supports multiple inputs or at least dual inputs. There is a menu option listed in the manual described as PBP which resembles Picture beside Picture in my mind. As such, you would be able to have on screen two different sources and view them simultaneously.

If you had nothing connected to the second source, you may be able to use this function/feature to shift your desired screen to one side or the other. I suspect this will split the screen in half, rather than provide a smaller shift to the side, but the research leads me to believe that may be your only option.

There is a function/feature within the manual referenced as freesync which appears to read the video signal and apply that to the display in a manner I did not research deeply. This may cause a shift in the desired direction, or not. It is reversible if needed by using the reset feature in the menu.

This information is contained in the [manual](https://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-32UD99-W) on pages 20-26 and is relatively comprehensive.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you've already assumed, the PBP splits it in half, but this is my last resort solution as well. I will have a look at FreeSync, thank you for your effort.