# Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor on Windows 10 Build 19041

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to fake a dual monitor for testing.

I have only one monitor and I have to hold a zoom presentation, and want to be able to see my notes while others see only the presentation.

The accepted anwser in [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor/796884) does not work, as right clicking on the desktop doesn't display screen resolution.

Comment: Windows 10 has something called virtual desktops. While I've not done much with them in Windows before I expect they would work for you. Press the "Task View" button on the taskbar or the Windows key + Tab, then press "New Desktop" at the top. You should be able to have the presentation and your notes on the separate desktops, I think.

Comment: The instructions you reference are for Windows 7 and back. As you have found out, they don't work in Windows 10.  If you REALLY need to fake a dual monitor setup.. several people on the link you provided said that [iDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com/) worked like a charm.  I suggest doing what @BeowulfNode42 suggests if at all possible.  Virtual Desktops are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but the issue has not been resolved directly for Windows 10.

In your case, try the [Spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/) app.
Your smartphone will become an additional (extended) display.
Your PC and smartphone must be on the same wi-fi subnet.

Moreover, you can use Spacedesk app to create a pure Fake diaplay on a single PC (Windows 10).
To do this, install **Spacedesk**'s Server and Viewer parts on this PC and give an additional IP address to your network adapter. You can use this IP to launch the Viewer part, which will become an extended display.