# Fake / virtual monitor in Windows 7?

Tags: display, resolution, desktop

I have a 1440x900 monitor and I want to do some video capturing at to 1080p, WQHD, 4K, etc using my same setup without having to fork out on higher resolution monitor.

One idea is to extend the desktop in windows 7 to a second, "fake" monitor with the desired resolution. I would then drag the application into the extended, faked monitor, maximize it from the keyboard and start recording via a hotkey. It would be unseen but capturing at the higher resolution.

Wondering if anyone has any insight into if it's possible? Is there a way to fake windows into showing a second monitor where I can extend the desktop across?

Any help appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: See this similar questions for ideas: http://superuser.com/q/62051/86828 http://superuser.com/q/10210/86828